How does dax week and year handle 31 dec 2023?
I'm creating calendar table.
When I use YEAR dax on a date, say 31 dec 2023, then it will return year as 2023.
But if I use WEEKNUM dax on this date,

Returns the week number for the given date according to the
return_type value. The week number indicates where the week falls
numerically within a year.

When I try WEEKNUM(31st dec 2023) then I get 53. Shouldn't this be 1?
And YEAR(31st dec 2023) gives me 2023. Shouldn't this be 2024? As this date is a Sunday and falls in week one of 2024 when analysing by week I want this to be week 1. I'm confused is this possible to do?

I presume you mean WEEKNUM()?
Weeks can have arbitrary rules applied to them as they don't align nicely with our calendar (see here for the pattern: https://www.daxpatterns.com/week-related-calculations/).
At the year cross over points, you can choose how weeks are treated (and subsequent week numbers calculated) by using the second argument. i.e. it is a business decision for you to make rather than a hard technical rule.



What's the diffrence between 1 and 17 in the above table?

No difference. 17 is just included to keep the sequence 11-17 logical and consistent.

When I try WEEKNUM(31st dec 2023) then I get 53. Shouldn't this be 1?
And YEAR(31st dec 2023) gives me 2023. Shouldn't this be 2024? As this date is a Sunday and falls in week one of 2024 when analysing by week I want this to be week 1. I'm confused is this possible to do?

Why would it be 1? 53 seems logical to me. Year will always give the actual year and has nothing to do with week number

In a 4 4 5 type of calendar, where week starts on Sunday, 31st Dec 2023 falls in the 1st week on 2024. Isn't it?

4 4 5 is a different type of pattern where you would have to implement the rules yourself. WEEKNUM() has nothing to do with 4 4 5

Ok so I can't make the YEAR and WEEKNUM to behave like the 4 4 5 rule?

They do not support 4 4 5 and have their own specific functionality. If you want 4 4 5, you will have to implement the pattern using your own rules.
